# Change mail signature from my application using gmail api

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-api

I am new to Gmail api.My requirement is to change signature of the gmail account through my application.
Ex:
Now my account signature is 
**Ramprasad**

And i want in this format

Ramprasad 
I am not available from 26-12-2014 to 30-12-2014

How to get this signature through my application using gmail api
Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Gmail API currently doesn't provide a way to change your signature. There is an [Email Settings](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_signature_settings) API that does allow for this, but only for users within a Google Apps domain and only by the domain administrator.